# Debugging iPhone App from Command Line

Tags: iphone, debugging, command-line

I can do it from XCode, but I want to be able to launch an iPhone App (on the device) from the command line. Is it possible?

Why? Because I want to capture some of the output for semi-automated testing. I'm guessing I need to use a debug build for NSLog output, but I'd also be interested to know about other methods for getting NSLog / stdio data back to the host Mac.

Comment: I could well be wrong but i thought you could not get at the cli on the iPhone unless it was jailbroken?

Comment: I think he is wanting to use the CLI on his computer to launch the app in debug mode on the phone and capture the output.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71753223/19309398

Answer (score 1):

There is a project on github called titanium_mobile (part of Titanium Developer).

I use a utility from that project called iphonesim.  It launches an iPhone app from the command line (though I am not sure how, I think there is a way to do that with SpringBoard.app).  If you take a step up one level in the Titanium Mobile code and look at builder.py you can see how they launch an app in the simulator and capture the output.

Comment: That's a very interesting piece of code to mine, thanks. I could almost get it working on the simulator - certainly learnt a lot about building a launching iPhone apps automatically. In the end I found a different solution to my specific need, but I think the technique is of interest in general.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I solved my specific need a different way. I needed to get data from the iPhone's accelerometers into a prototype app in Adobe AIR(Flash).

I used this app on the iPhone which drops UDP packets with X,Y,Z forces in them.
http://code.google.com/p/accelerometer-simulator/wiki/Home

Found that from this blog post which might be of interest to people trying to do other similar things.
http://ifiddling.blogspot.com/2009/01/dummy2.html

I used a Python script to present a server to Flash, grab UDP accelerometer packets, munge them into AMF and send them to Flash. Flash uses a socket to connect to this server and receive the accelerometer data.

A few parts, but it works nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this on the device if it is jailbroken. You can put a debug build and symbols on your device and run gdb on it. It is totally unsupported but I hear it works. Not sure if there is a good tutorial. Google?

Answer (score 0):

One method would be to use the [AsyncSocket](http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) class, and pass whatever data you want to log from the iPhone to a basic host app on the Mac, which NSLogs whatever it receives.  If you follow the EchoServer application, you should be able to integrate it in just a few minutes

Comment: This sounds like a good way forward. In the end I found a different solution to my specific need, but I think this would work.