# Attach lldb to iPhone from command line

Tags: ios, iphone, debugging, remote-debugging, lldb

While attaching lldb to iPhone works from within Xcode. It is flaky at times. I wonder if it is because XCode has some additional checks before attaching to a process in iPhone. I'd like to debug an iPhone app from command line. lldb has some tutorial that suggest using `platform select` but that command is unsuccessful in even connecting.

```
$ (lldb) platform select remote-ios
  Platform: remote-ios
 Connected: no
```

Am I missing something?

This question has been asked earlier but has no correct answers:

- [Debugging iPhone App from Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2138968/debugging-iphone-app-from-command-line)
- [Attach LLDB to app on iPhone connected to computer - Command line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353446/attach-lldb-to-app-on-iphone-connected-to-computer-command-line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is using [ios-deploy](https://github.com/ios-control/ios-deploy) e.g.

> ios-deploy --bundle=<bundle.app> --debug

The above command will install your application bundle to the attached iOS device, and launch it with an lldb session connected.